# WPF - databinding a grid where each cell, not row, holds a data item

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, grid

I'm writing a timetable application where the timetable is presented as a grid with time slots for rows and rooms for columns. I want to bind the grid to data items that are events which can be placed at available timeslots in the rooms.

Row headers like '8:00-9:00' should be fixed in the first column, and column headers like 'Rm 402' should be fixed in the first row.

A natural control for this would be a DataGrid, which provides for a table with column headers, but items in its ItemsSource correspond to rows, not cells.

One could use a Grid or a WrapPanel, but will I have to implement the header behaviors manually then?

What would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: as a possible solution: create a `DataTable` with many columns for rooms and a fixed number of rows for hours and use `DataTable.DefaultView` as DataGrid.ItemsSource

Comment: You could opt for a multiple grid setup. With grid #1 specifically responsible for displaying the first column. Grid #2 specifically responsible for displaying the first row. And finally grid #3 filling the remaining space of your view, and sharing size with the other grids using SharedSizeScope.